# NSOperation dependency and completionBlock

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

We're having a simple problem regarding NSOperationQueue, here's a simple operation logic:

```
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSOperation *operationA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"- Running operation A");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.2];
    NSLog(@"- Done operation A");
}];

NSOperation *operationB = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"- Running operation B");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
    NSLog(@"- Done operation B");
}];

[operationA setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"-- Completion Block A");
}];

[operationB setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"-- Completion Block B");
}];

[operationB addDependency:operationA];
[self.queue addOperations:@[operationA, operationB] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Here is the final output

```
2015-12-21 14:59:57.463 SampleProject[18046:310901] - Running operation A
2015-12-21 14:59:58.664 SampleProject[18046:310901] - Done operation A
2015-12-21 14:59:58.664 SampleProject[18046:310900] - Running operation B
2015-12-21 14:59:58.664 SampleProject[18046:310904] -- Completion Block A
2015-12-21 15:00:00.736 SampleProject[18046:310900] - Done operation B
2015-12-21 15:00:00.736 SampleProject[18046:310904] -- Completion Block B
```

As we can see, the **operation B** is executed before the **operation A**'s completionBlock. In our real application, we have many **operation A** and only one **operation B**  that is dependant on all **operation A**. But then the problem we have is that **operationB** is launched before the last **operation A**'s completion block has been called, which would normally give information to the **operation B**.

How would I make **operation B** to execute after all the **operation A**'s completion blocks?

Comment: Is switching to GCD an option? That API has all the tools you need. For this particular case barrier blocks is the thing you ar looking for. With these you can run many type A tasks in parallel and then add a barrier task of type B which cannot start before all A are completed and no new task can start before B is finished.

Comment: Could you give me a brief example of how it would work? I know a bit about GCD but not enough for this kind of task

Comment: Honestly, I'm no expert either but I read the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich there other day and in the middle of part 1 "Handling the Readers and Writers Problem" is discussed something that sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Comment: One can do with GCD,  as one can do anything writing Assembly. NSOperationQueue is built on GCD. Only it is much harder to implement. Try canceling dependent blocks on dispatch_queues. Free with NSOperations!  Try change operation priorities using GCD APIs without burning fingers. A barrier actually halts the thread on which the block is performed, while NSOperation does this in much lighter using KVC/KVO - by not becoming "ready" to execute - until operations you depend on become "finished". dispatch_queues continue running without "barriers". NSOperations rock!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found in your testing completion blocks are not 'part of the queue' instead they run outside of the Operation Queue (and on another thread). Thus Operation A's completionBlock will run at the same time (ish) as Operation B.

I suggest you refactor your code to remove all the completion blocks.

You say you are using the completionBlocks to pass information from operation A's to B, there are two options for this: Give B references to all the A's (not weak) so when B runs it can pick the results from all the A's. Or if keeping all the A's around until B runs is infeasible for some reason, then recreate your completionBlock's as another NSOperation:

```
NSOperation *operationA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do stuff
}];

NSOperation *operationATail = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do completionBlock stuff
}];

[operationATail addDependency:operationA];
[operationB addDependency:operationATail];
[self.queue addOperations:@[operationA, operationATail, operationB] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Comment: Well described. This is exactly what I ended up doing (I in fact created custom NSOperation subclasses on top of those already existing operations). I gotta say that it is much more clean that way. I forgot to explain in my answer so thanks for exaplaning it.

Comment: Why do you need to subclass NSOperation? by introducing the dependency you KNOW absolutely for sure that all dependent operations finished successfully BEFORE your other operation started. Therefore, they could simply share a data object to "pass needed information" and the later operation can assume the former has left it the desired information. you don't need subclassing here, or any "triggers" - at least not for the issue described.

Answer (score 0):

why can you not invoke the operation inside of completion block a, thats what a completion block is there for.

```
[operationA setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"-- Completion Block A");
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSOperation *operationB = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"- Running operation B");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
        NSLog(@"- Done operation B");
    }];
    [queue addOperations:@[operationB] waitUntilFinished:NO];
}];


[operationA setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"-- Completion Block A when we dont need B");
}];
```

There is some nicer ways to perform this instead by using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     [self operationB];
}
```

Comment: Because, as mentioned, I might have multiple operationA's and only one operation B. I don't want 1 operationB per operationA, does that make sense?

Comment: So why not set the completion block differently when you need to. So every time you need operation b to run after operation a completes, then set the completion block of operation a to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid completion blocks - they're out-of-queue mechanism unsuitable
   for synchronising any operations or their communications.
2. Introducing dependency (B depends on A) means B will only run AFTER A has completed successfully.
3. For this reason - any simple data object can be used to "pass the information" safely between these two operations - that could simply share it (it suffices that you create it outside the blocks defining both operations. When "B" runs, it can ASSUME that "A" has already put needed info in the data object, and simply access it.

   ```
   self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

   NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary new]; // data object for communication

   NSOperation *operationA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
     NSLog(@"- Running operation A");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.2];

     info[@"DoThis"] = @YES;
     info[@"DoThat"] = @NO;
     NSLog(@"- Done operation A");
   }];

   NSOperation *operationB = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
      NSLog(@"- Running operation B");

     if ([info[@"DoThis"] boolValue] NSLog(@"Op A said to do this.");
     if ([info[@"DoThat"] boolValue] NSLog(@"Op A said to do that.");

     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
     NSLog(@"- Done operation B");
   }];

   [operationB addDependency:operationA];
   [self.queue addOperations:@[operationA, operationB] waitUntilFinished:NO];
   ```